# Geometric ergodicity of dynamical system

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, ergodic-theory, stochastic-calculus

I'm working with dynamical systems defined by ODEs and SDEs, in this latter case gradient systems in particular, a special case of Ito diffusions.

I've read that under reasonable assumptions this gradient systems are *geometrically ergodic*, but I'm new to the field of Ergodic theory. Does geometric ergodicity mean ergodic system with some kind of "exponential convergence"?

Could you recommend a book/review paper/notes where ergodicity is introduced in the context of Hamiltonian systems and stochastic differential equations (such as Ito diffusions)?

Comment: ok, try this paper , you can read it free online :http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304414902001503